# axios get data react native expo IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, axios, expo

I'm building a mobile app,for android and IOS platform and i try to connect the back with the front, but i face a timeout error for the request on IOS, when it's work for android.

here my code:

```
const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [openToggle, setOpenToggle] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  let baseURL = null;

  Platform.OS === "android"
    ? (baseURL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000")
    : (baseURL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000");

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllUser = async () => {
      try {
        const users = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/api/user`);
        console.log("test");
        console.log(users.data);
        setUser(users.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("erreur", error);
      }
    };
    getAllUser();
  }, []);
```

I'm on a simulator for android and on real Iphone for IOS.

```
erreur [Error: timeout exceeded]
```

I'm on the same wifi network for the simulator and the iphone.

Any advice?

Comment: Is `10.0.2.2` the actual LAN IP of the machine running the backend? Because my guess is it's the virtual network IP assigned to the host inside the android simulator.

Comment: i think it is cause when i was using localhost instead of 10.0.2.2 i was getting the error : "network error" on android and IOS. but after a little search i see a have too put 10.0.2.2 and its works.

Comment: `localhost` won't work because it always refers to the current device. Which means your android or iPhone would try to connect to a backend running on the respective phone, which isn't the case obviously. Judging from your comment you didn't understand my question, so let me rephrase: open a command prompt and type `ipconfig` on Windows and `ifconfig` on Linux / Mac. Now look for the line(s) that say(s) IPv4 address. Your computer will most like have an IP like 192.168.1.X or similar.

Comment: Oh Yes, thanks you it's work with the ipv4!

Answer (score 0):

On android emulator 10.0.2.2 corresponds to the local machine. [More Information Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses) That is why it works on android.

On iOS, iOS simulator is sharing local machine internet so localhost or 127.0.0.1 will point to your local machine.

So you have to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 on iOS.

If you are running your app on your iPhone/Android device you have to connect your phone with the same wifi network and use your machine ipaddress

Check this https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

Or you can get the machine ip from where the packager is loading from following code

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { scriptURL } = NativeModules.SourceCode;
const scriptHostname = scriptURL.split('://')[1].split(':')[0];
```

Comment: OP is running their app on an actual iPhone.